# Moving files to new folder with a batch file - unexpected behavior

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying use a batch file to move a large set of files that are buried in a tree of sub-directories. The code is able to move the files into a directory, and create the directory if it doesn't exist, but some strange things are happening:

- If the batch file is in the lowest directory (a directory that only contains files that need to move) it will create the directory if needed then move the files into it. But, it will also create a new directory of the same name in the directory it just created, as if the for loop is continuing to gather new files.
- If the batch files is in any one of the higher directories, it will just create the directory and not move the file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am out of my depth with this level of batch programming.

```
@echo off &setlocal
title "Move to series folder"

for /r %%G in (*.prt) do (
    set "fpath=%%~dpG"
    set "fname=%%~nxG"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    if "!fname:~0,3!"=="25-" (
        if  not exist "!fpath!\Series 25" mkdir "!fpath!\Series 25"
        move "!fname!" "!fpath!\Series 25"
    )
    if "!fname:~0,3!"=="30-" (
        if  not exist "!fpath!\Series 30" mkdir "!fpath!\Series 30"
        move "!fname!" "!fpath!\Series 30"
    )
    if "!fname:~0,3!"=="40-" (
        if  not exist "!fpath!\Series 40" mkdir "!fpath!\Series 40"
        move "!fname!" "!fpath!\Series 40"
    )
    if "!fname:~0,3!"=="45-" (
        if  not exist "!fpath!\Series 45" mkdir "!fpath!\Series 45"
        move "!fname!" "!fpath!\Series 45"
    )
) 
Pause
```

Comment: You have identified the issue yourself. The `for /r` command begins the recursion of the `prt` files, and moves into the `do` portion as soon as it begins. That means as you make changes within the recursed directories, those can be picked up again and reprocessed. What you should do is to replace it with a `for /f` loop and change the parenthesized command to a recursive command which selects all of your `.prt` files before proceeding with the `do` portion. The `dir` command with its `/s` option, or the `where` command with its `/r` option would be the most common way of doing that.

Comment: As a side note, when you `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` within your loop, you need to match it with an `endlocal` before the end of each iteration. If you don't, and you have many iterations, you'll soon realise what will happen.

Comment: See also `help robocopy`.